# Shell stop script if find command fails

Tags: shell, find

Good day.

In a script of fine i have the following find command:

```
find -maxdepth 1 \! -type d -name "some_file_name_*" -name "*.txt" -name "*_${day_month}_*" -exec cp {} /FILES/directory1/directory2/directory3/ +
```

I want to know how to stop the script if the command does't find anything.

Comment: Im dealing with some stuff away from my PC right now, ill try it when i get back and mark it as correct if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GNU xargs` with the `-r` switch and a pipeline to ensure the output of `find` is passed to `cp` only if its non-empty.

```
find -maxdepth 1 \! -type d -name "some_file_name_*" -name "*.txt" -name "*_${day_month}_*" \
       | xargs -r I{} cp "{}" /FILES/directory1/directory2/directory3/
```

`I{}` is a place-holder for the output from the `find` command which is passed to `cp`,

The flags, `-r` and `I{}` represent the following according to the `man xargs` page,

```
-r, --no-run-if-empty
      If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run
      the command.  Normally, the command is run once even if there is
      no input.  This option is a GNU extension.

-I replace-str
       Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with
       names  read  from  standard input.
```

Comment: Im going to test this out as soon as i can and upvote when possible

Answer (score 1):

You may add `-exec false {}` so you get a false exit status when something is found (which makes it a bit upside-down though)

```
if find . -name foo -exec echo ok ';' -exec false {} +
then
    echo 'not found'
    exit
fi
echo found
```

See similar question in stackexchange: [*How to detect whether “find” found any matches?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13860/how-to-detect-whether-find-found-any-matches), in particular [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13860/how-to-detect-whether-find-found-any-matches#answer-341042) which suggests the `false` trick